# Why does Laravel only want to use model with lowercase letter?

Tags: php, laravel

Im working on a Laravel project and was making a new model with a controller and migration. When I created that model i accidentally named it with lowercase letters like `order.php`. I have tried to change it so the first letter is uppercase like it is supposed to be but Laravel just keeps the lowercase letter one and doesn't use the one I want. I have tried to delete the model and everything associated with it and rebuilding it. I have also tried the `composer dumpautoload` command and reinstalling the vendor directory completely but it is still looking for the lowercase letter one.

So how do I make it so Larvel looks for the right Model?

Comment: where have you used this model?? you have to change everywhere you referenced this model.

Comment: I just created the model with artisan and haven't used it anywhere else

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Give us more information on what you do mean with "Laravel keeps the lowercase letter and don't use the one I want"

Comment: the only error i get is when I try to open the model with VSC (I added the error to the question)

Comment: how is this even related to laravel?? its vs code error..just re import the project folder and this error will be gone.

Comment: oh i'm so sorry, I didn't know it was unrelated. Everywhere i looked I saw my model file with lowercase letters so I thought it was something else. Thank you so much for your help en again i'm really sorry for the confusion